# Docker pull: Error response from daemon: EOF

Tags: docker

I keep getting EOF error when trying to pull images:

`docker pull dpage/pgadmin4`

```
Pull complete
942bbf3d7389: Downloading   1.82kB/1.82kB
fbe23c71dc3b: Download complete
7c1be9e99602: Download complete
ccc31a15f27f: Download complete
617b6e01309f: Download complete
e6cfa0ba7132: Download complete
9dd539b143fa: Downloading   3.15kB/3.15kB
6f3ff58d53db: Download complete
a79e40a556fb: Download complete
b05884a10df3: Download complete
3a39531f7518: Download complete
0337d3baf297: Downloading   9.88kB/9.88kB
c7a9de9c5d61: Download complete
unexpected EOF
```

I've tried to change the network and use my mobile hotspot. Sometimes it works and sometimes it does not.